# How to share database settings across the projects in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have got two projects in separate windows, and in one of the projects I have set up several data sources (in the Database tool window). These settings are not visible in the other project. Is it possible to share the settings between the projects in the IDEA?

Comment: Try import other project as module.

Comment: That is one option, but  I would not rather have dependency between the projects.

Comment: Here is the same question in community https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999655-Use-same-settings-for-all-projects-